# How to define fix action for Go checker using go/analysis?

Tags: go, analysis

I have recently written a Go checker using `golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis` and `golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/singlechecker` and I've managed to write my own custom file manipulation mechanism (keeping track of file offsets etc.) but I felt that I was fighting the system.

There seems to be a `Fix` flag defined in [https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/checker](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/checker?tab=doc) but I have no idea how to use it or hook into the system that uses it.

It's also available to be defined

```
-fix
        apply all suggested fixes
```

when checker is compiled with `singlechecker`:

```golang
import (
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/singlechecker"
)

var (
    Analyzer = &analysis.Analyzer{
        Name: "name",
        Run: run,
    }

    // Can't define a "fix" flag because golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/checker
    // defines it and flags cannot be redefined.
    // Fix = flag.Bool("autofix", false, "apply fixes automatically")
    Fix bool
)

func main() {
    // NOTE:
    // Don't do this at home. This should be properly integrated with
    // "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/checker" flags (specifically -fix
    // flag) but I have no idea how to do that and the documentation is non existent.
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
            if arg == "-fix" {
                Fix = true
                break
            }
        }
    }

    singlechecker.Main(Analyzer)
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation about it either.
The code that's supposed to be run when `Fix` flag is enabled it here: https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/268ba720d32c891185aa340e8851e215f23173db/go/analysis/internal/checker/checker.go#L265

Any clues how to use it?

Answer (score 4):

could be done like this:

```
    pass.Report(
    analysis.Diagnostic{
        Pos:     be.Pos(),
        Message: fmt.Sprintf("do not compare errors directly, use errors.Is() instead: %q", oldExpr),
        SuggestedFixes: []analysis.SuggestedFix{
            {
                Message: fmt.Sprintf("should replace %q with %q", oldExpr, newExpr),
                TextEdits: []analysis.TextEdit{
                    {
                        Pos:     be.Pos(),
                        End:     be.End(),
                        NewText: []byte(newExpr),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

good place to start reading is https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis#Diagnostic

Answer (score -1):

You can just provide flag `-fix=true` when running your checker. `singlechecker` will register that flag by running [checker.RegisterFlags()](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/go/analysis/singlechecker/singlechecker.go#L50). And then, passed flags will be parsed in [analysisflags.Parse()](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/go/analysis/singlechecker/singlechecker.go#L63)

Comment: Sure, that's the easy part but the question is how to define the actions that this flag will trigger?